# android/kotlin : Material Button show a grey box and then the box disappear

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, materialbutton

[short clip of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtvTb.jpg)

In the clip above you will be able to see the problem better.
Switching between Fragments user can see on the icon on the material button a grey box shaped element for short time.

I tried using both the emulator and a real device. Since im using Lottie in my project, custom made svg imported icons it started.. I think I am not quite sure what causing this.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="14dp"
android:clickable="true"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
app:cardElevation="8dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewWorkout"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_training_arm" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/workoutDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageViewWorkout"
        android:text="workout date"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/workoutName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageViewWorkout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/workoutCalories"
        android:text="workout name"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/workoutCalories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/workoutName"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageViewWorkout"
        android:text="workout calories"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/workoutName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/delete_foreground" />
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/editButton"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/deleteButton"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_foreground" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

Comment: what is @drawable/edit_foreground ?

Comment: android:background="@drawable/edit_foreground". that is a vector icon that i imported

Comment: Don't use `android:background="@drawable/edit_foreground"` for an icon. Use `app:icon="@drawable/your_icon"`